# How to append column of one data frame as row of another data frame based on row/column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames, df1:

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
y1
y2
y3
y4
y5
```

and df2:

```
    y1  y2  y3  y4  y5
z1
z2
z3
z4
z5
```

I want to append the values of df1 as a row in df2 by comparing the row/column names in the dataframes. I did this using Numpy but I want to do this using Pandas. Kindly help.

Comment: whats your desired output?

Comment: How did you do it using Numpy?

Comment: I want the information in columns of df1 to be appended as rows in df2 after ensuring that the information is being assigned to the same row/column name.

Comment: but in your example there are no common column names, they are just transposed versions of each other. Have a read of [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

can you just create a transponse of df2 and then append/merge/"add" to df1?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Comment: All the rows names in df1 might not be available in df2...hence I want to first compare the row/column names before appending.

Comment: if you use merge with "how=inner" you will only add columns that are present in both dataframes.

A other solutin would be 2 (iter-)loops combined and iterateover the data. But that is pretty slow and and not good practice... but if you only need to do this once and for a smaller amount of data...   this might just be your dirty trick to do it....